# Run useEffect() when value of state doesn't change but get's set

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

is there a way to execute `useEffect()` when the value of a state does not change but is set?

Example code:

```
 const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState('')
  const [serialNumber, setSerialNumber] = useState('')
  const [requestType, setRequestType] = useState<RequestType>()

  const serialNumberSubmitHandler = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setRequestType(RequestType.SERIAL_NUMBER)
    setFormValue(serialNumber)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    props.updateIdRequestType({ requestType, id: formValue })
  }, [formValue])
```

How can I execute `useEffect()` when `formValue` gets set but the value is the same as the prev state?
At the moment it wont execute when same value as `prev state` is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `useEffect` to do the job, you can do that in `serialNumberSubmitHandler` itself.

```
  const serialNumberSubmitHandler = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setRequestType(RequestType.SERIAL_NUMBER)
    setFormValue(serialNumber)
    props.updateIdRequestType({ requestType, id: serialNumber })
  }
```